# Compare two arrays and retrun element with same index

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I have 2 inputs `adress` and `street`. I need to make 2 arrays size `street`. One array with odd numbers and another with even numbers. Than i need to reverse odd array. Than I need to check what array contains input `adress` and to return same index element from another array.
This is error what is show to me:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file test/solution.swift, line 6

```
func overTheRoad(address: Int, street: Int) -> Int {
    var odd = Array(stride(from: 1, through: street * 2, by: 2))
    let even = Array(stride(from: 2, through: street * 2, by: 2))
      odd.reverse()
    if address % 2 == 0{
      let index = even.firstIndex(of: address)!
      return odd[index]
    }else{
      let index = odd.firstIndex(of: address)!
      return even[index]
    }
}
```

This is how to suppose work:
You've just moved into a perfectly straight street with exactly n identical houses on either side of the road. Naturally, you would like to find out the house number of the people on the other side of the street. The street looks something like this:

```
Street
1|   |6
3|   |4
5|   |2
  you
```

Evens increase on the right; odds decrease on the left. House numbers start at 1 and increase without gaps. When n = 3, 1 is opposite 6, 3 opposite 4, and 5 opposite 2.

Example (address, n --> output)
Given your house number address and length of street n, give the house number on the opposite side of the street.

```
1, 3 --> 6
3, 3 --> 4
2, 3 --> 5
3, 5 --> 8
```

Comment: Hey Stefan, welcome to the site! A lot of your question's body is statements like "I need to ... then I need to ...". Rather than trying to explain your solution, could you take a step back and more clearly articulate the actual problem you're trying to solve? Once people understand that, we can try to come up with a solution, which might just be completely different than the path you've started going down (or maybe not! But we need to understand the question to be sure).

Comment: You also need to show how you are calling this `overTheRead` function. In other words, what values are you passing in for `address` and `street`? Also note that you need to validate that `address` is actually in the `even` or `odd` array. Using `!` is a bad idea as you can see from your crash.

Comment: I saw your edit. It's still too solution oriented. Completely ignoring arrays, evens, odds, or any other implementation details. As HangarRash suggested, could you please provide some example inputs of `address` and `street`, and the correct answer you're looking to get?

Comment: The code you posted works without any crashes if `address` is in the range `1...street*2`. Please post actual code that results in the error you reported, including how you call the function.

Comment: By the way, in Swift you can simplify `address % 2 == 0` to just: `address.isMultiple(of: 2)`

Comment: Your latest update still doesn't show how you are calling `overTheRoad` that results in the crash. It looks like there is a bug in your test code (oh the irony) and it is passing in an invalid combination of address and street.

Comment: It is more an arithmetic problem than array problem : odd address = position * 2 - 1,  even address = 2*(street - position +1). From this and invert formulas you can find the address that is facing any input address.

Answer (score 1):

```
func overTheRoad(address: Int, street: Int) -> Int? {
var odd = Array(stride(from: 1, through: street * 2, by: 2))
let even = Array(stride(from: 2, through: street * 2, by: 2))
  odd.reverse()
if address % 2 == 0{
  guard let index = even.firstIndex(of: address) else { return nil } 
  return odd[index]
}else{
  guard let index = odd.firstIndex(of: address) else { return nil }
  return even[index]
}
```

}

Instead of force unwrapping, you should unwrap it safely with a guard let (or if let) statement. In case of no address value is found in the array, you can return nil.

Comment: Still have error:   main.swift:15:149: warning: string interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?

Comment: @StefanStojkovic Husamettin changed the return type of this function from `Int` to `Int?`. This is necessary model the fact that there isn't necessarily an answer when the given house doesn't even exist. You need to handle this optional in your calling code.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements @Alexander. Actually, I intended to handle the invalid input case. I consider the actual problem is outside of the function instead. Crash cases must be handled one or another way, but as long as there are invalid inputs an error still will exist.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Hüsamettin Eyibil's answer, there one big thing that could be improved here: You're generating 2 arrays here, only to query them for a single value and discard the rest. Half the time, each of them isn't even used a single time!

There's actually a pretty simple, closed-form math solution:

```
func overTheRoad(address: Int, street: Int) -> Int {
    let totalHouseCount = street * 2
  
    guard address <= totalHouseCount else {
      fatalError("The address number \(address) is too high for a street that's only \(street) houses long!")
    }

    return totalHouseCount - address + 1
}

// Some test cases:

XCTAssertEqual(overTheRoad(address: 1, street: 3), 6)
XCTAssertEqual(overTheRoad(address: 2, street: 3), 5)
XCTAssertEqual(overTheRoad(address: 3, street: 3), 4)
XCTAssertEqual(overTheRoad(address: 4, street: 3), 3)
XCTAssertEqual(overTheRoad(address: 5, street: 3), 2)
XCTAssertEqual(overTheRoad(address: 6, street: 3), 1)

XCTAssertEqual(overTheRoad(address: 3, street: 5), 8)
```

Here I chose to `fatalError` on invalid input, but it might make sense to just return `nil` instead.

Comment: While this is a vastly simpler solution it doesn't address why the OP's code is crashing. The OP's code works just fine if a valid combination of address and street are passed into the `overTheRoad` function.

Comment: Perhaps that's why I chose to start my answer with "Adding on to Hüsamettin Eyibil's answer ..." :)

Comment: But the other answer doesn't address the actual cause either. Yes, avoiding the force-unwrap is a good way to go, but again, the OP's code doesn't actually crash with valid input. This means neither answer is actually solving whatever the problem really is (I suspect faulty test code at this point).

Comment: @HangarRash Ah I see your point. Yeah, I suspect he's testing with invalid inputs. One of our two snippets would point that out, though